# Spark java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected operator in scalar subquery

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop-yarn, cloudera

I'm facing an issue while running a relatively huge query in Spark (Cluster Mode) on Cloudera Cluster.

This is a part of query:

```
...


CASE WHEN (gender_code = 'M') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `2114`,
 CASE WHEN (gender_code IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(TRIM(gender_code)) > 0) THEN 
  1 ELSE 0 END `1780`,
      CASE WHEN (( gender_code = 'F'
 ) AND ( procedure_code between '54000' and '55920' )
) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `4054`,
      CASE WHEN (NVL(gender_code, 'U') = 'U') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `92501`,
      CASE WHEN ((getConstant("FILE_TYPE_CODE") = 'PC' AND gender_code in ('1', 'M')) OR (getConstant("FILE_TYPE_CODE") IN ('ME', 'MC', 'PC') AND gender_code = 'M')) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `2125`,
      CASE WHEN (date_of_birth is NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `92971`,
/*THIS ONE IS CAUSING ISSUE */( select first(number_of_member_first_name) from( select count (distinct x.member_first_name) as number_of_member_first_name, date_format(x.paid_date,'yyyyMM') as ym from dataset x where cast( datediff(x.date_of_service_from,x.date_of_birth)/365 as INTEGER ) > 60 group by date_format(x.paid_date,'yyyyMM') ) s where s.ym= date_format(a.paid_date,'yyyyMM') ) `93251`,

      CASE WHEN (date_of_birth is not null AND LENGTH(TRIM(date_of_birth)) > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `92504`,
      CASE WHEN (member_city IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(TRIM(member_city)) > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `1638`,
      CASE WHEN (member_city is NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `92961`,
      CASE WHEN (member_state is NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `92621`,
      CASE WHEN (member_state = getConstant("CLIENT_CODE")
) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `2260`,
      CASE WHEN (member_state IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(TRIM(member_state)) > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `1961`,
      CASE WHEN (member_zip_code IS NOT NULL AND LENGTH(TRIM(member_zip_code)) > 0) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `1793`,
      CASE WHEN (member_zip_code is NULL) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END `92622`,
      CASE WHEN (( date_of_service_from > paid_date ) AND ( date_of_service_from is NOT NULL )
...
```

This huge query has many scalar sub queries in its select part. The part that I mentioned with "/*THIS ONE IS CAUSING ISSUE */" runs perfectly fine when I test the code in my local machine (click on the link to see the screen capture):
[screen capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IDUxy.png)
but when the same query against same files runs in Cloudera cluster, it gets following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected operator in scalar subquery: LocalRelation <empty>, [first(number_of_member_first_name, false)#405275L, ym#404801]

at scala.sys.package$.error(package.scala:27)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.optimizer.RewriteCorrelatedScalarSubquery$.evalPlan$1(subquery.scala:373)
```

Anyone can help me to figure it out why it runs okay in my local machine but gets error in Cloudera Cluster?

Comment: Have you executed sub-query in hive or Impala shell (select first(number_of_member_first_name) from( select count (distinct x.member_first_name) as number_of_member_first_name, date_format(x.paid_date,'yyyyMM') as ym from dataset x where cast( datediff(x.date_of_service_from,x.date_of_birth)/365 as INTEGER ) > 60 group by date_format(x.paid_date,'yyyyMM') ) s where s.ym= date_format(a.paid_date,'yyyyMM') ) , look like number_of_member_first_name value is null hence throwing error.

Comment: Hi Shambhu. I ran the similar query in Impala and it works!
The query that I ran:
select sum(number_of_member_first_name) 
from( select count (distinct x.member_first_name) as number_of_member_first_name,
from_timestamp(to_timestamp(x.paid_date, 'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyyMM') as ym 
from dc.mc_dcdpc02_6 x 
where cast(datediff(to_timestamp(date_of_service_from,'yyyyMMdd'), 
to_timestamp(date_of_birth,'yyyyMMdd'))/365 as integer) > 60 
group by from_timestamp(to_timestamp(x.paid_date, 'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyyMM') ) s;

 But still getting the same error on Spark on Cloudera Cluster.

Comment: I even added “and x.member_first_name is not null” to the most inner query but still it gets same error when running on Spark on Cloudera Cluster, while it runs perfectly fine in my local machine on Spark stand alone. I noticed that Spark version in my local machine is 2.3.1 but in cloudera cluster is 2.3.0 Do you think that would be the reason?

Comment: The best practices are spark version must be same in your local as well cluster. I believed, could the version mismatch reason, hence changed local and you pom file if you are using and try it out. Hope will work for you!

Answer (score 1):

After debugging carefully. It appears that my Dataset's view gets dropped and so it didn't have any data to provide to most outer query, resulting to have aggregate function on a null value and throwing error.